# Objective c : fastest method to overlay a video

Tags: objective-c, video, overlay, avasset, avmutablecomposition

After recording a video, I want to overlay it with a dynamic uiview which is updated related to the current video frame timestamp. In fact I am trying to do the same thing as Vidometer application.
Following the Apple [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH9-SW17), I am able to extract the video frame as a buffer and I overlay it with the UIImage of my UIView.

The steps are :

1. Extract video frame:

   ```
   CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [assetReaderVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
   if (cancelled) {
       completedOrFailed = YES;
       [assetWriterVideoInput markAsFinished];
   }
   CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
   ```
2. Update my UIView's subviews following the frame timestamp:

   ```
   mergeTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer));
   [self updateWidget:mergeTime*1000];
   ```
3. Get the UIImage of my UIView:

   ```
   mSurcoucheImage = [self imageFromSurcouche];
   ```

   With

   ```
   -(UIImage*)imageFromSurcouche{
   CGSize mSize;
   mSize = CGSizeMake(self.mSurcouche.bounds.size.width, self.mSurcouche.bounds.size.height);
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mSize, NO, 0.0);
   if (videoOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
       CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), mSize.width, mSize.height);
       CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), M_PI);
   }
   [self.mSurcouche.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return image;
   }
   ```
4. Apply a filter to keep the alpha of my UIImage:

   ```
   CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
                           inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:options];
   filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
   [filter setValue:maskImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
   [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
   outputImage = [filter outputImage];
   CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
   ```

   With

   ```
   colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(__bridge id)colorSpace forKey:kCIImageColorSpace];
   ```
5. Render my UIImage to the video frame buffer

   ```
   [ciContext render:outputImage toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer bounds:[outputImage extent] colorSpace:CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()];
   ```

   With

   ```
   eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
   ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:eaglContext options:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]}];
   if (eaglContext != [EAGLContext currentContext])
      [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:eaglContext];
   ```

I am trying to reach the same performance as Vidometer application which have an overlay duration less than the video duration, but I am far with this method.

**Question 1: Is this method the best performing?**

**Question 2: A also see another [method](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) which use AVMutableComposition, but I don't think that I can synchronize my UIView with the video frame timestamps. Can I?**